# LaunchOption in FinishedLaunching always null (Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: ios, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I'm implementing remote notification for my iOS app, and I'm trying to catch notification payloads when the app is not running. The problem is that, when FinishedLaunching is called, launchOption parameter is always null. In other cases, when app is in background or active, notifications work good. 
I don't understand why, based on references and blog posts, it should work. This is the code I'm using:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
            //new UIAlertView("launchOption", launchOptions != null ? "Yes" : "No", null, "").Show();
            if(launchOptions != null && launchOptions.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey))
            {
                //new UIAlertView("launchOption", "launchOption != null", null, "");
                this.viewModel.Loading(false);

                NSObject result;
                if (launchOptions.TryGetValue (UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey, out result)){
                    NSNotification notification = result as NSNotification;
                    DispatchPushNotification(application, notification.UserInfo);
                    Console.WriteLine ("Got a local notification: {0}", notification);
                }
            ...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did u find solution for this?, I am also facing similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I resolved changing the code that retrieves the payload. I've noticed that every time I was using `options.TryGetValue(...)` the input value in launch option was `null`. Removing this line and using the following did resolve my problem.

```
if (launchOptions != null && launchOptions.ContainsKey (UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)) { 
   Console.WriteLine ("launchOption != null and LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey present"); 
   NSDictionary notification = launchOptions.ObjectForKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey) as NSDictionary;
   if (notification != null) 
      // do something
   }
}
```

I don't know if it is a bug, I didn't have too much time to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact problem, payload was coming as null. The issue was I wasn't type casting the finished launching option as below:

```
NSDictionary userInfo = (NSDictionary)options [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

After type casting, I started getting proper payload. It seems you are also directly accessing the launchOptions.